# C doesn't open functions

Tags: c, function

So, my C doesn't want to open my functions. I don't know where to look further as I don't have any idea what I did wrong in this one. It works fine with another exercise.
Here's what I've written:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int hello();
int sum(int);
int k, i, getal1, getal2;
int goobye(void);

int main(void)
{
    int hello();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Give 2 numbers <100 : ");
        scanf("%d%*c%d%*c", &getal1, &getal2);
        int sum(int k);
    }
    int goodbye(void);
}

int hello()
{
    printf("Welcome, this program will ask you to solve 1 sum");
    return 0;
}
int sum(int k)
{
    int som, som2;
    som = getal1 + getal2;
    printf("What is the sum of %d %d? %d", getal1, getal2);
    scanf("%d", &som2);
    if (som == som2)
    {
        printf("According to you, the sum of %d and %d equals %d. That is correct", getal1, getal2, som2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("According to you, the sum of %d and %d equals %d. That is not correct", getal1, getal2, som2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int goobye(void)
{
    printf("Thanks for your cooperation.");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *doesn't want to open my functions* Have you debugged it? What compiler are you using? What is your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: `int hello();` -> `hello();` in `main()`. Same for `goodbye();`

Comment: `int sum(int k);` --> `sum(k);`

Comment: you are calling function `sum()` by sending an unitialised variable `k` as an argument.

Comment: What is `k` for in `sum` function?

Answer (score 1):

in main function you should call a function without type

```
int main(void)
{
hello();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Give 2 numbers <100 : ");
    scanf("%d%*c%d%*c", &getal1, &getal2);
    sum(k);
}
goodbye();
}
```

Edit the main function like this

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problems, I do have some extra errors but I'll find out how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly you need to read about the syntax while calling functions.
- Also why you assign a certain return type to a certain function i.e. the difference between `int hello();` and `void hello();`.
- Also you have placed `return 0` statement at multiple places which would end your program before you actually want it to!

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  void hello();
  int sum(int);
  int k, i, getal1, getal2;
  void goobye(void);

  int main(void)
  {
      hello(); //no return type mention when calling  a function
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          printf("Give 2 numbers <100 : ");
          scanf("%d%*c%d%*c", &getal1, &getal2);
          sum(getal1, getal2);//you wish to calculate the sum of these two numbers i suppose
      }
      goodbye();
      return 0;
  }

  void hello()
  {
      printf("Welcome, this program will ask you to solve 1 sum");
      // return 0 here will end your program
      //return 0;
  }
  int sum(int getal1, int getal2)
  {
      int som, som2;
      som = getal1 + getal2;
      printf("What is the sum of %d %d? %d", getal1, getal2);
      scanf("%d", &som2);
      if (som == som2)
      {
          printf("According to you, the sum of %d and %d equals %d. That is correct", getal1, getal2, som2);
      }
      else
      {
          printf("According to you, the sum of %d and %d equals %d. That is not correct", getal1, getal2, som2);
      }//again the same issue with return 0 as above
      //return 0;
  }

  void goobye(void)
  {
      printf("Thanks for your cooperation.");//again the same issue with return 0 as above
      //return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Calls are not perform because you don't call the functions, you just redeclare them. This is probably a copy/paste error, but in the end, the calls don't happen.
I modified you code hunk and added comments

```
int main(void)
{
    int hello(); //here is a forward declaration of hello()
    hello(); // calls hello
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Give 2 numbers <100 : ");
        scanf("%d%*c%d%*c", &getal1, &getal2);
        int sum(int k); // forward declaration of sum()
        sum(k); //call sum on k
    }
    int goodbye(void); // forward declaration of goodbye
    goodbye(); //call goodbye
    //careful your original code has a typo; you wrote goobye()
}
```